# Code Analysis CA1811 not working inside a form about "uncalled private coode"

Tags: c#, winforms, analysis

In Visual Studio 2012 update 3, I have some uncalled private code inside the Winforms codes, not inside MyForm.Designer.cs, but in MyForm.cs, but CA fails to report CA1811. If I have uncalled private code in other classed, the check is OK. I tried VS 2012 in two workstations, the result is consistent.

Is this a known bug? or any workaround or fix?

Comment: I have the same issue, so I have reported this issue to Microsoft. I noticed that update 4 is due to be released. So lets see what happens.

Comment: I have update 4 and have this issue.  I created a method like so:  

    private void testxxx(){}

.  This method should be identified as uncalled private code but it is not.

Comment: Same thing in VS2012 Update 5 and VS2015 Update 1, as of today. May be a bug or a very cryptic feature...